# Display Alternate Message (KeyDown)

Tags: c#, events, keydown

I am creating a simple practice program where if I am going to press "Enter" the first message that will be displayed is "Enter a word", then if I press again "Enter", the second message will be "Hello." I am really new to KeyDown events and I'm just starting to learn it bit by bit. Any help is appreciated.

Here's the code that I've tried so far. But the output is not what I wanted to be.

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "1")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter a word");


            }

            else if (textBox1.Text == "1")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hello");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: both your if statements test for the same clause. Either none will fire, or only the first (because of the else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would really need to save your state before you press Enter key second time. In the following implementation I saved the state in boolean "State" variable, as task only requires there to be 2 possible states.

```
    private bool State = false;

    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            if (State == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter a word");
                State = true;
            }

            else if (State == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hello");
                State = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

If you had more states, you could use different variable like string or use private method which performs some work to determine next state.

Comment: this worked. i just added state = false below MessageBox.Show("Hello"). and now the messages display alternately. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your two `if` clauses are the same (`textBox1.Text == "1"`). You shouldn't use a TextBox to track your state, anyway. Try creating a `private int time = 1;` field in your form source code and check it instead. Don't forget to increase it by 1 every time you find out you pressed "Enter".